# i want to access my website by ip and domain but want to google indexing ip

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, seo

i want to access my website by ip and domain but i don't want google indexing ip. taking example of google, i can access google by both doamin `https://www.google.com/` and ip `http://202.166.193.159/`.
i tired 301 redirect in htaccess by doing like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^202\.166\.193\.159$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.google.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

this doesn't give me the solutions. I want to access by both but don't want indexing by ip

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect for Googlebot with root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^googlebot
# With your IP !
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^202\.166\.193\.159$
# With your domain !
RewriteRule ^ https://www.google.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```